# How to have tfs publish specific folder using web deploy

Tags: tfs, msbuild, webdeploy

I need to publish a specific folder in my project to my web site using tfs builds. I know tfs copies to a drop folder but I also need it to publish to my web server when I queue a new build. Is there anyway I can do this? I currently have web deploy installed on my server and I have tested it and know it works. Would these be some type of build definition? I can only find sample definitions that copy to a UNC path.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Are you using a XAML build or vNext Build of TFS2015+ and VSTS?

Comment: Several information would help to answer your question: Which version of TFS are you using? Are you using a XAML build or vNext Build of TFS2015+ and VSTS? If you need to copy the files to a non UNC Path, where is it that you want to copy them (FTP, Specific Cloud)?